# Neo4J: How to find all the paths starting from node till the first node with certain label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

hope you can help me with this, so basically I'm looking for a way to Find all paths till the first node of certain label (the query should explore all the paths from a node and stop when a node with a specific label is found).

I have two labels (A and B)

let us say we have the following connectivity

```
A1>B1>B2>A2>B6>A6
A1>A4>A5 
A1>B3>A3>B8>A7
```

i want to know how can i return path starting from A1 till the first node of label A only therefore the output should be like this:

```
A1>B1>B2>A2
A1>A4
A1>B3>A3
```

screenshot of the graph is below
[image]

what im looking for as a result should be like the below
[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use variable length path matching.  It tells that you can navigate thru the nodes from point A to point A2 in any number (*) of jumps.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

```
 MATCH p1=(a1:A1)-[*]-(:A2)
 MATCH p2=(a1)-[*]-(:A4)
 MATCH p3=(a1)-[*]-(:A3)
 RETURN p1, p2, p3
```

Node B will also be included in the path (p1, p2, p3) so no need to add it in the query.

Comment: actually your code is looking for the node name, however i want only to search a path till the first node of based on the label only, because my database my include infinite number of A nodes

Comment: You could remove the name property yo your path only includes label and then use the [shortestPath](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/) function to get to the first node of the given label **A**.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH path= (start)-[r *]->(end:`A`)
WHERE start.name='A1'
with start, end,nodes(path) as path
where all(x in path where (id(x)=id(start)) or (id(x)=id(end))  or (all( la in labels(x) where la<>'A' )))
return start,end,path;
```

参考：https://blog.csdn.net/aofavx/article/details/134708781

Comment: Could you translate the chinese characters before the link into english?